# How to create an array with incremented values in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, increment

I accepted the input from the user and stored it in the variable "n". But, when I try to execute this code, I get java.lang.NullPointerException.

```
public class JavaApplication58 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = null;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            a[i - 1] = i;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("" + a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `int a[] = null;` What were you expecting?

Comment: When I didn't initialize the array, I get RuntimeException - variable not initialized.

Comment: Read some tutorials on arrays or `ArrayList` to learn more about how they work.

Comment: What on earth do you want to archive with `a[i - 1] = i`?

Comment: @reporter I want to assign a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3] to 1, 2, 3 etc.

Comment: @Ishtiaq and why does `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {a[i] = i+1;}`not work?